# Label text not updating when using StringProperty kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to update the label text in my app, but when I try it doesn't work, my code is down here, shouldn't this be enough to change the text?

.kv label

```py
MDLabel:
    id: id_utilizador
    text: root.id_utilizador
```

.py alter label text

```py
class MyClass():
    id_utilizador = StringProperty()

    def change(self):
        self.id_utilizador = "test"
```

Comment: You have to trigger some action in order to change the property.

Comment: You are not showing enough code. What is the relationship between `MyClass` and that `MDLabel`? Please post a [mcve].